Communicating with a list of components
The following code snippet does exactly what I expect, which is to provide a list of 3 items that expands to show the numeral for the written number when clicked. My question is whether a Dictionary is the proper way to track the state?
Do I really have to maintain a copy of the state on this page, or is there a way to bind the click event to directly modify the value of the property on the component rather than a local copy of the status which is bound to the components value?
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <ul>
            @if(Items != null)
            {
                foreach(var kvp in Items)
                {
                    <li @key="kvp.Key" @onclick="@(e => Toggle(kvp.Key))">@kvp.Key <CollapsibleRow @bind-Expanded="expanded[kvp.Key]">@kvp.Value</CollapsibleRow></li>
                }
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    Dictionary<string, bool> expanded = Items.Select(o => new KeyValuePair<string, bool>(o.Key, false)).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);

    void Toggle(string key) 
    {
        
        expanded[key] = !expanded[key]; 
    }

    static Dictionary<string, string> Items = new()
    {
        { "One", "1" },
        { "Two", "2" },
        { "Three", "3" }
    };
}


In this case I would move away from the Dictionary, and use a view model instead, so that the expanded tracking is held with the object itself. I may have mixed up where you have used the number and the name of the number, but hopefully you get the idea.
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <ul>
            @if(Items != null)
            {
                foreach(NumberVm item in Items)
                {
                    <li @onclick="@(() => Toggle(item))">
                        @item.Name <CollapsibleRow @bind-Expanded="@item.Expanded">@item.Number</CollapsibleRow>
                    </li>
                }
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    List<NumberVm> NumbersList = new()
    {
        new NumberVm{ Number = 1, Name = "One" },
        new NumberVm{ Number = 2, Name = "Two" },
        new NumberVm{ Number = 3, Name = "Three" },
    }

    void Toggle(NumberItem item) 
    {
        item = !item;
    }

    private class NumberVm
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Expanded { get; set; }
    }
}


+1 as this is certainly an improvement, and I should have written my code this way to begin with so as to better convey my question. But... what I'm really wondering is why I need to track the state on my page or even on a view model. What I'd prefer is for the component to track its own state and for me to be able to communicate from parent to child that it should toggle. Still wrapping my head around the Blazor way of thinking so maybe what I'm asking is not possible and/or would be an "anti-pattern" in regard to the goal of wanting to write platform agnostic code. Hope that makes sense.

You need to maintain state if you wish to preserve the state across page changes.  If not, you can maintain state internally.
Here's a Bootstrap accordion version of your code where the state is maintained by each AccordionItem.
Accordion
<div class="accordian">
    @ChildContent
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}

AccordionItem
<div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header">
        <button class="@_headercss" type="button" @onclick="OnChangeState">
            @this.Header
        </button>
    </h2>
    <div class="@_bodycss">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          @ChildContent 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string? Header { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public bool IsInitiallyOpen { get; set; }

    private bool _open;
    private string _headercss => _open ? "accordion-button" : "accordion-button collapsed";
    private string _bodycss => _open ? "accordion-collapse collapse show" : "accordion-collapse collapse";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _open = this.IsInitiallyOpen;
    }

    private void OnChangeState()
    {
        _open = !_open;
    }
}

Home
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<Accordion>
    @foreach(var kvp in Items)
    {
        <AccordionItem Header="@kvp.Key">@kvp.Value</AccordionItem>
    }
</Accordion>

@code {
    static Dictionary<string, string> Items = new()
    {
        { "One", "1" },
        { "Two", "2" },
        { "Three", "3" }
    };
}



Sorted the naming

Here is the code I ended up with that gets rid of the "middle man", so to speak, so that I can directly call the Toggle method on the component rather than having to rely on a property binding. Although not shown here, this also reduces the amount of code necessary in the component itself now that it doesn't need to expose a parameter.
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <ul>
            @if(Items != null)
            {
                foreach(var kvp in Items)
                {
                    <li @key="kvp.Key" @onclick="@(e => collapsibleRows[kvp.Key].Toggle())">
                        @kvp.Key 
                        <CollapsibleRow @ref="collapsibleRows[kvp.Key]">@kvp.Value</CollapsibleRow>
                    </li>
                }
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    Dictionary<string, CollapsibleRow> collapsibleRows = new();

    static Dictionary<string, string> Items = new()
    {
        { "One", "1" },
        { "Two", "2" },
        { "Three", "3" }
    };
}

